# Class calculating a variable

Tags: objective-c, class-variables

I am making a simple command line app about shapes. I have made the colour and number of sides variables and have made them settable properties inside an if statement. I need to be able to get the name of the shape but am not able to just set it as a variable. So the class needs to calculate and return the name rather than it being a settable property.

Could you please advise me of the best way to do this as I am not sure. I tried putting the if statement in the implementation file but XCode doesn't like it.

Any advice would be appropriated.

Class Header file:

```
@interface shape : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *numberOfSides;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property int *sides;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *colour;

void waitOnCR (void);

Main.m 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "shape.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        //Array of colours thats index is randomly selected from when the program is run
        NSArray *colours = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red",@"Blue",@"Green", @"Yellos", @"Ornage", @"Purple", @"Pink", nil];
        NSUInteger random = arc4random() % [colours count];

        NSLog(@"Enter a number from between 3-8");

              float user;

        scanf("%f" , &user);

        if (user == 3)
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setSides:@3];
            [myShape setColour:@"Red"];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ and is called a %@", [myShape colour], [myShape sides], [myShape name]);
        }
        else if (user == 4)
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setSides:@4];
            [myShape setColour:@"Blue"];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ and is called a %@", [myShape colour], [myShape sides], @"Square");
        }
        else if (user == 5)
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setName:@"Pentagon"];
            [myShape setNumberOfSides:@"5"];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ and is called a %@", [colours objectAtIndex:random], [myShape numberOfSides], [myShape name]);

        }
        else if (user == 6)
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setName:@"Hexagon"];
            [myShape setNumberOfSides:@"6"];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ and is called a %@", [colours objectAtIndex:random], [myShape numberOfSides], [myShape name]);

        }
        else if (user == 7)
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setName:@"Heptagon"];
            [myShape setNumberOfSides:@"7"];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ and is called a %@", [colours objectAtIndex:random], [myShape numberOfSides], [myShape name]);
        }
        else if (user == 8)
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setName:@"Octagon"];
            [myShape setNumberOfSides:@"8"];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ and is called a %@", [colours objectAtIndex:random], [myShape numberOfSides], [myShape name]);
    }
```

Comment: Should we all look into our crystall balls, or would you rather provide the code?

Comment: could you please post the code snippet with that error here?

Comment: Could you, please, explain what the problem is. Can't you modify Shape class or what?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate name you can write something like this. 
Shape+CalculableName.h

```
#import "Shape.h"

@interface Shape (CalculableName)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *calculatedName;

@end
```

Shape+CalculableName.m

```
#import "Shape+CalculableName.h"

@implementation Shape (CalculableName)

- (NSString *)calculatedName {
    if (self.name) {
        return self.name;
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.colour, self.numberOfSides ];
}

@end
```

And offtopic, Using of switch operator is better practice than using ifs